# Python returning streaming data from tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.6, tweepy

I am building a module source_collect.py that shall contain modules I will use to to collect data from various sources and return raw data that I can use a second module to parse.

I am able to print or write the streaming data to a json file, but I am not able to return the data through the return function. Do anybody have som pointers on what i am missing out on?

```
import tweepy

import twitter_credentials as cred

class my_streaming_object(tweepy.streaming.StreamListener):

    def on_data(self,raw_data):
        try:
            print('......streaming...')
            self.raw_data = raw_data
            return self.raw_data

        except BaseException as e:
            print(f'Code broke :{str(k)}')
            return False

    def on_error(self,status_code):
        if status_code ==420:
            print(f'Twitter limit stop{self.status.code}')
            return False


class twitter_data:

    def stream_tweets_keywords(self, keywords):
        # get twitter access
        authen = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(cred.CONSUMER_KEY,cred.CONSUMER_SECRET)
        authen.set_access_token(cred.ACCESS_TOKEN,cred.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
        test = authen.get_username()
        print(f'You are Authenticated as Twitter user {test}')
        print('....Initialising twitter stream......')
        # stream tweets
        try:
            streamer = my_streaming_object()
            my_stream = tweepy.streaming.Stream(authen, listener=streamer)
            my_stream.filter(track=keywords, is_async=True)
            return
        except BaseException as b:
            print(b)
            return False




if __name__=='__main__':

    run = twitter_data()
    run.stream_tweets_keywords(['Hydrogen','Nikola'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by changing my logic. 
Made a function in the DB_store module that I used within this module handling the streaming response to db.

The change in logic was instead of having this module return then picking it up in the next function input. I nested the next function in this one.

I dont now if this is a good practice, so if any body have a good OOP guideline for the overall logic it would be appreciated.